# Replace whole object in react state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state

Is there a way to update the `state` with a state structure like this

```
this.state = {
      structure: [
        {
          selected: false,
          name: "a",
          key: "a",
        }, {
          selected: false,
          name: "b",
          key: "b"
        }, {
          selected: false,
          name: "c",
          key: "c",
        }, {
          selected: false,
          name: "d",
          key: "d"
        }
      ]
}
```

I want to update the state. I am doing it this way:

```
 _onPress = (obj, index) => {
    const oldStateSelected = obj.selected;
    const newStateObject = Object.assign({}, obj);
    newStateObject.selected = !oldStateSelected;

    const oldState = _.cloneDeep([...this.state.structure]);
    oldState.splice(index, 1);
    const newState = oldState.push(newStateObject)

    this.setState({
      structure: [newState]
    });

  }
```

However, that returns me a new state of

```
{ structure: [4] }
```

I think the problem is, that I am modifiing the state in place instead of replacing it?!
When I `console.log(oldState)` after removing the element from the `array`, I see that it says `oldState (3) [Object, Object, Object]`.
But when I open it, there are `4` array elements. The element I wanted to remove with `splice` is still in there.

Any ideas?

Comment: [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) return value is the new length of the array, not the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in this line:

```
const newState = oldState.push(newStateObject);
```

**[array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)** will not return the updated array, when we use push it will update the original array, so you need to assign the variable oldState value to state variable structure.

Use this:

```
_onPress = (obj, index) => {
    const oldStateSelected = obj.selected;
    const newStateObject = Object.assign({}, obj);
    newStateObject.selected = !oldStateSelected;

    const oldState = _.cloneDeep([...this.state.structure]);
    oldState.splice(index, 1);
    oldState.push(newStateObject)

    this.setState({
        structure: oldState      //here
    });

}
```

Check this snippet:

```js
let a = [10,15,20];
let b = a.push(20);

console.log('a = ', a);
console.log('b = ', b);
```

Comment: thanks. why does the `splice` not work though? It does not remove the elements as described in my Q.

Comment: do console.log(index) and check the result, index should be proper.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.push` is not returning the array. Just `push` and do

```
this.setState({
  structure: oldState
});
```